# How to draw a line?

Tags: draw, line, page, picture-mode

Here is a page that is US letter size, in landscape orientation. There is a single line going from (0,0) to (11in, 7.5in).

[image]

Is this possible to do in TeX?

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in,margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,0){\line(3,-0.35){4}} % <-- I have no idea how this works
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

I have no idea how the noted code line above works. But it does draw a line and for some reason it add text. Can I get this working so that it draws the required line?

Comment: Switch to `tikz` instead of the picture env is it quite outdated. Tikz even come with a "smallish" manual. It has many examples on this site or if you google `tikz example`

Comment: @WilliamEntriken US letter size is not 11in by 7.5in, is it a typo?

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the `\put(0,0){\line(3,-0.35){4}}` inside the `picture` environment of your example, it is a failed attempt to draw a line of length 4 (expressed in terms of `\unitlength`) starting from point (0,0) and going in direction (3,-0.35). This can't work well, because:

- you haven't specified the value of `\unitlength`, thus you get the default of `1pt` (combined with the other data, the line would be very short);
- the *a* and *b* used in `\line(a,b){length}` are limited to integers in the range [-6,6], so -0.35 is clearly out of question.

You can find more information about the `picture` environment on [www.dickimaw-books.com](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/picturecode.shtml), but you should already have realized that it is rather limited in features (it's a very old environment). Just before closing this chapter, the following example gives more sensible output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\put(0,0){\line(5,-3){4}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Due to the limitations of the `picture` environment (the lines it can draw have a very limited number of slopes, as they come from glyphs of a special font), it is better here to use Ti*k*Z, as daleif suggested. Doing what you want is very easy using the `current page` node. See section *Referencing the Current Page Node – Absolute Positioning* in the [Ti*k*Z and PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for more details.

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}               % don't print the page number

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw (current page.north west) -- (current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need not to use large TikZ package for such trivial task. One `\pdfliteral` is sufficient. For example in OpTeX format:

```
\useoptex % OpTeX format

\margins/1 (11,7.5) (1,1,1,1)in % letter landscape, 1in margins    
\pgbackground={\pdfliteral{q 1 w 0 0 m \_bp{\pdfpagewidth} -\_bp{\pdfpageheight} l S Q}}

\nopagenumbers \null % nothing to print

\bye
```